# Ng For loop does not wrk properly

Tags: ionic2

I am beginner ionic2

Actually I am using FCM Plugin for Push notifications.

This is my app component.ts

```
     FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(d){
          if(d.wasTapped){  
            console.log(d);
           var nav=self.appCtrl.getActiveNav().setRoot(NotificationsPage);
       })
```

It's wrk perfect.and also when I click Notifications page redirect to respective page(Notifications page).

I retrieved data from firebase collections and assign to array.

Array variable name is Notifications.I consoled the array value.It's work fine.

Display Array into UI using virtualScroll.

Below my html code.This is Push notifications respective page(Notifications page)

```
<ion-card class="card" [virtualScroll]="Notifications">
      <ion-item (click)="navigate(Notifications.value.TYPE,Notifications.value.FROM,Notifications.value.$key,Notifications.value.TO,Notifications.value.MSG,Notifications.value.STATUS,Notifications.time)" *virtualItem="let Notification">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img  *ngIf="!Notification.userval.FILE" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/default.png?alt=media&token=a64af538-17a7-46e1-9e38-383c1df060cf">
          <img *ngIf="Notification.userval.FILE" [src]="Notifications.userval.FILE">
        </ion-avatar>
         <p>{{Notification.value.MSG}}</p>
         <p>{{Notification.time}}</p>
         <p style="text-align:right;color:#334bfa;">{{Notifications.value.TYPE}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card>
```

Below My Notifications page Component(ts file).

```
          this.authservice.getalluser().first().subscribe(namelist=>
              {
                 var users=[];
                 namelist.forEach(userval=>
                 {
                   users.push(userval.val());
                 })

                for(var i in val)
                {
                this.Time=val[i].SEND_TIME;
                var timeagoIns  = timeago();
                var result=timeagoIns.format(this.Time);
                console.log(result);
                 var user=users.filter(users=>users.USER_ID.toString() === val[i].FROM.toString());
                this.Notifications.push({
                     value:val[i],
                     time:result,
                     userval:user[0]
                  })
                Console.log(this.Notifications);
             })
```

array values does not update UI.But i consolesd the Notifications value.It's work fine.

Why doesnot update the UI in array value.

How to fix this issue.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you update your array like this?

```
push.on('notification', (data) => {
    // update array
});
```

If you are updating your array that way then UI should not update. Because your array is now out of ngZone. In this case you can use this,

```
push.on('notification', (data) => {
   this.ngZone.run(() => {
       // update array
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks For ur reply.I will Update array value in app component file.When click on notifications redirect to respective page.How should update array value.I doesnot pass any pushnotifications value to array.Actually I retreived data from firebase collections on respective page.Then why i will update array value.

Comment: Could you please edit you question and add array updating code?
Otherwise it is very difficult to give answer assuming many things.

Comment: Notifications or this.Notifications?

Comment: Another possible issue,
[virtualScroll]="Notifications" 
*virtualItem="let Notifications"

both contain same variable name.

Comment: this.Notifications

Comment: app opened.then going to Notifications page It's work perfect.When I click Push Notifications and goiing to respective page does not wrk why?

Comment: I think you should use this.Notifications.push({}) instead of Notifications.push({})
And also change this *virtualItem="let Notifications" to this *virtualItem="let Notification"

Comment: It's work.But Some times cannot Update.why? How to fix this.Any other way to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you please update this code with you latest code?

Comment: I Update my code .also change this *virtualItem="let Notifications" to this *virtualItem="let Notification"

Comment: Is there any particulate case when the UI is not update? Something like when single notification or multiple notifications found.

Comment: No,I does not Update any value on click push notifications.Clicked on notifications page redirections and it's not work some times.Opened my app and go to notifications It's work.Why?

Comment: My question is I retrieved data with out any pblm.But Its cannot display UI.

Comment: I didn't find any thing wrong.
Last one thing you can change is this,
 FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(d){
this.ngZone.run(() => {
          if(d.wasTapped){  
            console.log(d);
           var nav=self.appCtrl.getActiveNav().setRoot(NotificationsPage);
});
       })